# Why doesn't ctrl+u send SIGKILL? stty says it should

Tags: shell, tty, kill, signals

I can interrupt a program by pressing `ctrl+c` in the shell. Often this kills the program but some programs trap the signal and keep running.

I want to be able to kill such programs more aggressively and did some research. I read that `stty -a` will list tty shortcuts. Here is the output:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 27; columns 213; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Let me draw your attention to

```
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; [...]
```

Two of those look familiar: `^C` and `^D`, and it looks like `^U` should send sigkill, which I believe should be like `kill -9`.

In my particular case, I want to kill ddd, which is otherwise difficult to close sometimes. If I `crtl+u` from the shell, it has no effect, although `kill -9` on its PID will kill it.

Am I wrong in interpreting this output from `stty -a`? Should `ctrl+u` send SIGKILL? Why didn't this work as expected? Or, how can I conveniently send SIGKILL from the shell (i.e. the shell which ddd was launched from)?

Comment: `stty` doesn't say it should, it just print the word "kill". I can print "I'm sick", but it can't tell you wether I'm really sick or not.

Comment: Your confusion aside, I wonder what awful programs you have to run that much that you feel the need of a *shortcut key* for `SIGKILL` ;-) Anyways, try `^\ `; most programs don't bother to catch `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: The questioner already named one such program.

Answer (score 6):

That kill is for character assassination, not death by signal. It should be documented in a the `termios(4)` man page,

> Erase and kill processing occur when either of two special characters,
>        the ERASE and KILL characters (see the Special Characters section), is
>        received.  This processing affects data in the input queue that has not
>        yet been delimited by a newline NL, EOF, or EOL character.  This undelimited data makes up the current line.  The ERASE character deletes
>        the last character in the current line, if there is any.  The KILL character deletes all data in the current line, if there is any.

or `termios(3)` on linux

> VKILL  (025, NAK, Ctrl-U, or Ctrl-X, or also @) Kill character  (KILL).
>                 This  erases  the input since the last EOF or beginning-of-line.
>                 Recognized when ICANON is set, and then not passed as input.

Comment: Or `man stty`:  `kill CHAR                               CHAR will erase the current line`

Comment: "character assassination" ROTFL